# Deriving a Typeable instance for (':)

Tags: haskell

I am trying to derive a Typeable instance for (':)

I am using DataKinds and [*].

I have TypeOperators, StandaloneDeriving and PolyKinds enabled

I cannot derive an instance of typeable

I have tried

```
deriving instance Typeable (':)
```

and

```
deriving instance Typeable ':
```

and

```
deriving instance Typeable ((':))
```

but they all get parse errors.

I know that if I write

```
data List a = Cons a (List a) | Empty

deriving instance Typeable (Cons)
```

I get the expected outcome but I do not wish to rewrite my existing code to use a custom list type.

Comment: Very interesting that you can derive an instance for `'[]`, but not for `':` this way. For anyone else who wants to try this, you'll need DataKinds, PolyKinds, DeriveDataTypeable, and StandaloneDeriving.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This seems to work

```
 deriving instance Typeable '(:)
```

Presumably the `'` is designed to mark the "whole type constructor", including if it's sectioned? Seems a bit weird to me. This is consistent with tuples however, where you would write

```
'(a, b)
```